# How to change stretchiness of liquid?

Tags: fluid-simulation

How do I make it so that candle wax drops stick to the original part for longer?

Comment: Can you share your file?

Comment: It's as simple as setting up a fluid simulation and playing with the viscosity.

Answer (score 1):

The "stretchiness" you refer to is called **viscosity**.

The settings to change it can be found here, and there are even a few presets to get you started:

[image: Fluid viscosity settings]

[The Blender Manual](http://www.blender.org/manual/physics/fluid/domain.html) explains these settings well. See the Viscosity section.

Comment: Hey, what settings should be increased to fix this?